# Inno Setup - How to get the path of the current copied file from Files section

Tags: inno-setup

I have .iss script with the following code:

```
[Files]
Source: "..\*.ext"; DestDir: "{tmp}\Test\"; \
   AfterInstall: DoSomething('{path}'); Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs;

[Code]

procedure DoSomething(path: string)
...
end;
```

I need to call the procedure `DoSomething()` and pass to it the path of the current copied file for every file. How can I get the path of the current file from the `[Files]` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [documentation of the `AfterInstall` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall):

> Use [`CurrentFilename`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_currentfilename) to check for which file the function is called.

*(link added by me)*

---

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "..\*.ext"; DestDir: "{tmp}\Test\"; \
   AfterInstall: DoSomething; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs;

[Code]

procedure DoSomething;
var
  Path: string;
begin
  Path := CurrentFilename;
  { ... }
end;
```